# How to transfer SOL in a contract using the playground?

Tags: solana-program, transactions, rust

I tried a few variations and I cannot get the instruction to work or be defined correctly. I have this client code and I welcome suggestions about how to code the instruction variable -
Error -

> ```
> Uncaught error: instruction is not defined
> ```

```
import {TransactionInstruction} from '@solana/web3.js'
console.log(pg.PROGRAM_ID.toString());
// Get latest blockhash info
const blockhashInfo = await pg.connection.getLatestBlockhash();
console.log(blockhashInfo);
// Create transaction
const tx = new web3.Transaction({
  ...blockhashInfo,
});
console.log("tx ==",tx);
const programId = new web3.PublicKey(pg.PROGRAM_ID.toString());

// Add our hello world program instruction
const account1 = new web3.PublicKey("BkQTFDah5ogoy9FtcGKKvQr67cjrZABDYVY9om9o188s");
// 4dGDp3BuTaXiqJwwJhh9abUBBm6hMhRkidttr5N4Cemm
const account2 = new web3.PublicKey("4dGDp3BuTaXiqJwwJhh9abUBBm6hMhRkidttr5N4Cemm");

const amount = 1000;
 

// encode the payment instruction
 
const instructionObject = new TransactionInstruction({
  instruction, // this is not defined
  amount,
})
tx.add(
  new web3.TransactionInstruction({
    programId: pg.PROGRAM_ID,
    keys: [
      {pubkey: account1, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},
      {pubkey: account2, isSigner: false, isWritable: true},
      // add any additional keys here
    ],
    //data: Buffer.from([]),
      data: instructionObject.toBuffer(),

   
  })
);
console.log("tx added ", tx);
// Sign transaction
tx.sign(pg.wallet.keypair);
// Send the transaction to the Solana cluster
const txHash = await pg.connection.sendRawTransaction(tx.serialize());
console.log(txHash);
```

The Rust contract is as follows -

```
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    program_error::ProgramError,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
};

/// Custom program errors
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
pub enum CustomError {
    InsufficientFundsForTransaction,
}

impl From<CustomError> for ProgramError {
    fn from(e: CustomError) -> Self {
        ProgramError::Custom(e as u32)
    }
}

/// Transfers lamports from one account (must be program owned)
/// to another account. The recipient can by any account
fn transfer_service_fee_lamports(
    from_account: &AccountInfo,
    to_account: &AccountInfo,
    amount_of_lamports: u64,
) -> ProgramResult {
    // Does the from account have enough lamports to transfer?
    if **from_account.try_borrow_lamports()? < amount_of_lamports {
        return Err(CustomError::InsufficientFundsForTransaction.into());
    }
    // Debit from_account and credit to_account
    **from_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? -= amount_of_lamports;
    **to_account.try_borrow_mut_lamports()? += amount_of_lamports;
    Ok(())
}

/// Primary function handler associated with instruction sent
/// to your program
fn instruction_handler(accounts: &[AccountInfo]) -> ProgramResult {
    // Get the 'from' and 'to' accounts
    let account_info_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let from_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;
    let to_service_account = next_account_info(account_info_iter)?;

    // Extract a service 'fee' of 5 lamports for performing this instruction
    transfer_service_fee_lamports(from_account, to_service_account, 5u64)?;

    // Perform the primary instruction
    // ... etc.

    Ok(())
}

entrypoint!(process_instruction);

fn process_instruction(program_id: &Pubkey, accounts: &[AccountInfo], instruction_data: &[u8]) -> ProgramResult {
    // Match the first byte of the instruction data to determine which instruction to execute
    match instruction_data[0] {
        0 => {
            instruction_handler(accounts)?;
        }
        // ... etc.
        _ => return Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData),
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Update your question with exactly what didn't happen the way you expected it to, including the text of error messages with full stack traces.

Comment: There is no error message from the given code because instruction is not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no initialization for `instruction` variable in your client code, it's normal that it throws an error.

Here is an example on how you can achieve what you want:

**Program:**

```
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    msg,
    program::invoke,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    system_instruction,
};

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize)]
pub enum MyInstruction {
    Transfer { amount: u64 },
}

entrypoint!(process_instruction);

pub fn process_instruction(
    _program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    match MyInstruction::try_from_slice(instruction_data)? {
        MyInstruction::Transfer { amount } => process_transfer(accounts, amount),
    }
}

fn process_transfer(accounts: &[AccountInfo], amount: u64) -> ProgramResult {
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();
    let from = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?.key;
    let to = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?.key;

    msg!("Transfering {} lamports from {} to {}", amount, from, to);

    let transfer_ix = system_instruction::transfer(from, to, amount);
    invoke(&transfer_ix, accounts)
}
```

**Client:**

```
class MyInstruction {
  constructor(obj: object) {
    for (const key in obj) {
      this[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
}

const MyInstructionSchema = new Map([
  [
    MyInstruction,
    {
      kind: "struct",
      fields: [
        ["discriminator", "u8"],
        ["amount", "u64"],
      ],
    },
  ],
]);

const encodeIxData = (ix: object = {}) => {
  return Buffer.from(
    borsh.serialize(MyInstructionSchema, new MyInstruction(ix))
  );
};

const fromPubkey = pg.wallet.publicKey;
const toPubkey = new web3.PublicKey(
  "4dGDp3BuTaXiqJwwJhh9abUBBm6hMhRkidttr5N4Cemm"
);
// Transfer of 1 SOL
const amount = new BN(1 * web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL);

const tx = new web3.Transaction();
tx.add(
  new web3.TransactionInstruction({
    programId: pg.PROGRAM_ID,
    keys: [
      { pubkey: fromPubkey, isSigner: true, isWritable: true },
      { pubkey: toPubkey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
      {
        pubkey: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
        isSigner: false,
        isWritable: false,
      },
    ],
    data: encodeIxData({ discriminator: 0, amount }),
  })
);

const txHash = await web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(pg.connection, tx, [
  pg.wallet.keypair,
]);
console.log("Tx signature:", txHash);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am testing and get this - "SOL balance: 8.288851
    Uncaught error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: instruction spent from the balance of an account it does not own" I checked the pg wallet and that is valid, also I have a bal. I checked various vars and they all look ok. It works until the actual sendTxn part and then it flags this ownership issue.

I am using the pg and I assumed that injects the credentials into the client?

Comment: I tested again with the Rust code too and it all works now. Before I was using my old Rust code thinking it was a client only problem.